# как правильно векторизировать dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

у меня есть некий фрейм , который я буду засовывать в алгоритм , предварительно векторизировав . Я использую CountVectorizer . Я могу векторизировать каждый column фрейма , но получатся разные матрицы , хотя мне , видимо , нужна одна . Что я делаю неправильно?

данные:
[very long article],[date],[price]

Comment: и да , векторизирую текст

Comment: Приведите небольшой пример данных в вопросе...

Comment: норамьная ли идея перевести векторизированный articles в pandas df , затем просто добавить price , как новый столбец ? с date то же самое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CountVectorizer` по умолчанию возвращает разреженную (`sparse`) матрицу - это важный момент, потому что в большинстве случаев после векторизации у вас получится огромное количество столбцов (`features`) - 30K - 100K столбцов это нормальное количество столбцов. Если использовать обычную неразреженную матрицу, то может не хватить памяти. Поэтому Есть смысл добавлять новые признаки (`features`), `date` - в вашем случае, к разреженной матрице.

Если я правильно понимаю вашу модель данных, `price` - это то, что вы хотите предсказывать (`target`). Поэтому нет смысла добавлять его к векторизированной (скорее всего разреженной) матрице.

PS как векторизировать столбец типа `datetime`:

```
In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2018-01-01', freq='999S', periods=10)})

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
                 date
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00
1 2018-01-01 00:16:39
2 2018-01-01 00:33:18
3 2018-01-01 00:49:57
4 2018-01-01 01:06:36
5 2018-01-01 01:23:15
6 2018-01-01 01:39:54
7 2018-01-01 01:56:33
8 2018-01-01 02:13:12
9 2018-01-01 02:29:51

In [26]: df['date'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9
Out[26]:
0    1514764800
1    1514765799
2    1514766798
3    1514767797
4    1514768796
5    1514769795
6    1514770794
7    1514771793
8    1514772792
9    1514773791
Name: date, dtype: int64
```